# Components positions react dom

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

How do I use useRef to get the position of a component directly from the dom
In this case I want to be able to get the position of the pageItem

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import PageItem from '../components/pageItem'
const LandingPage = () => {


    return (
        <div className={classes.mainContainer}
        >
            <PageItem/>
 
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the ref you can use any element API like [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

```
const LandingPage = () => {
  const divRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(divRef.current.getBoundingClientRect());
  }, []);
  return (
    <div ref={divRef} className={classes.mainContainer}>
      <PageItem />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add ref to custom elements like

```
 <PageItem/>
```

You can wrap custom elements with default elements like div or send refs through props to child default elements